# RTOS vTasDelayUntil doesn't work

Tags: rtos, freertos, lora

I'm using ESP-IDF via PlatformIO in Visual Studio Code with a TTGO module and want to use the vTaskDelayUntil() function to have an unblocking delay.
Unfortunately when using it, nothing happens in that task.

#define INCLUDE_vTaskDelayUntil 1 is already set in the config.

Here is my code:

```
void blink_task(void *pvParameter)
{
  TickType_t xLastWakeTime;
  const TickType_t DelayLED = 250/portTICK_PERIOD_MS;
  xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();

  bool LEDstatus = false;

  gpio_pad_select_gpio(BLINK_GPIO);
  gpio_set_direction(BLINK_GPIO, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);

  for(;;){
    vTaskDelayUntil( &xLastWakeTime, DelayLED);
    if (LEDstatus == false)
    {
        gpio_set_level(BLINK_GPIO, 0);
        LEDstatus = true;
    }
    else
    {
        gpio_set_level(BLINK_GPIO, 1);
        LEDstatus = false;
    }       
  }
}


extern "C" int app_main(void)
{
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(&blink_task, "blink_task", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 5, NULL, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

vTaskDelay() works perfectly fine but has massive lags when I add another Task. That's why I wanted to use vTaskDelayUntil.

Does anyone have an idea what went wrong here?

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards,

Martin

Comment: "has massive lags" - what do you mean?  FreeRTOS at its name suggests is a real-time operating system, and therefore entirely deterministic - if you are experiencing anything different, then it is entirely down to your code, not FreeRTOS.  Both delays are "blocking" - what do you mean "unblocking delay" - did you perhaps mean "non-blocking"?  Even then vTaskDelayUntil is not non-blocking.  Moreover I would imagine that `vTaskDelay(n)` is simply implemented as `vTaskDelayUntil( xTaskGetTickCount(), n)`, in any case, so is little different from what you have.

Comment: You had a problem, you decided on a solution that does not work, and are now asking about that problem.  This is known as an X-Y problem - you would do better to ask about the original problem - it looks like your problems are more fundamental that just how to use the delay functions.

Comment: Hello Clifford,
thanks for your responses.
I investigated further and you are right. It's not the delay which is wrong. Some part of my code provoked restarts on an irregular basis. So it looked like the delay doesn't work but in fact the program was just rebooting. vTaskDelay now works fine even with more than one task.

The vTaskDelayUntil function stil doesn't work at all even though I use it exactly as described.
I think this is still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

FreeRTOS use premonition system to schedule task, that's means if a task with higher priority exist in running state, scheduler never switch to another task.
check the priority of all task and to be sure task with higher priority not do work for long time!
Another problem may in stack size, increase it in heap size and check it again.